# installing Anaconda on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, anaconda

Currently I have python 2.7 installed, and I decided to install Anaconda (same version).
My questions are:

1. What is the safest way to do it? Uninstall python 2.7 first?
2. Can I move packages installed on my old python version manually (without reinstalling them again)?
3. Should I change something in my PATH variable afterwards?
4. I'm working with Pycharm. Is there a way to change automatically the interpreter of all existing projects?

My motivation:

I'm in charge of ~50 students (Python noobies) in a university course. Since I'm having some difficulties supporting the installation of each and every one of them, I thought that moving to Anaconda can help me save some time and future problems. Since some of them already started working on their projects, I want to do this transition as clean as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your motivation for installing it? I installed it once but found no additional benefit from using it - all packages it contains can be installed manually, so I uninstalled it shortly.

Comment: @jettico I edit the question, see the motivation above. BTW why did you uninstall it? did you encounter some other difficulties?

Comment: Yes, that's a good motivation. No, no difficulties, I just found it to be superfluous for me. All the packages I need I install from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ Your workflow probably needs regular mass-updates for which Anaconda might be a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anaconda installs a completely separate Python, so there is no need to do anything with the old one. The Anaconda installer sets the PATH variable automatically.

As to the packages, your best bet if there is a package you need that doesn't come with Anaconda is to install it with conda, or using pip if it isn't available with conda.

I don't know about PyCharm but if you search StackOverflow you should find another question about the same.

Comment: Thanks. So do you suggest uninstalling python 2.7, or let them live together?

Comment: There's little harm in leaving it there, but I suppose you can save some disk space and potential confusion if you remove it. If you're referring to a system Python that came with the OS (like on Linux) then you should just leave it alone.